# How to Increase content Porter Importing File Size

Tags: content-porter-2009

We were trying to import Publications using Content Porter 2009. Even if we try to import one single component. We are getting below error

`unable to upload package.Access to server could be restricted or package is too large`

We also tried with one component also still facing above error.

Can someone suggest a solution or what could be the reason for this error. We also tried modifying web.config of content porter to accept larger files. Still its failing.

This is happening only with our One Environment only. We even tried to import empty file also still the error message.

Comment: As it happens with only one component, it has probably nothing to do with size, check diskspace on server,access to folder etc. logs and eventviewer might give you more clues

Comment: Depending on how you set up your dependency filters, even a single component could result in a large export (for example all components that the component links to couple be exported, and then all components they link to, and so on and so on). The same applies to import, if you have exported with dependencies... How big is your zip file?

Comment: We tried Importing from primary level with no components. We got the same error.

Comment: Did you restart IIS after making the change?

Comment: Yes we have restarted IIS as well as Tridion Services.

We tried to import a `blank` folder from Parent Publication that too failed

Comment: If you Remote Desktop on to the Tridion server can you access the Content Porter webservice on the following URL: `http://localhost/ImportExportService/ImportExportService.asmx` (assuming that Tridion is available on localhost)?  If so, can you access the web service in a browser on a remote machine (where you are running the Content Porter client) e.g. `http://<tridion-url>/ImportExportService/ImportExportService.asmx`.   Can you verify in the IIS logs whether the package is making it on to the server but being rejected there?

Comment: Is the URLScan running on that server? By default it blocks any http traffic over 30 MB.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are some guidelines for configuring Content Porter for first time use in the SDL  Tridion Live Content document [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_ContentPorter_2009_SP2/concept_88C03F01866C4771BB564FD2CB5433AA) (login required).

If you are using IIS 6 then you will need to change the metabase property called AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed

If you are using IIS 7 then you need to add the 'maxAllowedContentLength' attribute:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209752100" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Comment: Yes we have tried that already but got the same error.

Comment: Please note that the value above is only 200MB. Have you tried to add a couple of zeroes? And you changed this in <TridionRoot>\Content Porter\ImportExportService\web.config right?

Comment: - C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\Content Porter\ImportExportService
we updated web.config mentioned above and Tridion's web.conf and tried still it is failing.

Comment: Can you connect to the Content Porter webservice after connecting via Remote Desktop to the Tridion server (`http://localhost/ImportExportService/ImportExportService.asmx`)?  Can you connect to this remotely from where you're running the Content Porter client (`http://<tridion-server-url>/ImportExportService/ImportExportService.asmx`)?  Have you checked the IIS logs to see if the connection is being made?

Answer (score 8):

Is there free space on the server? CP is first uploading packages into it's own location. Can you check if there're files created? It's under `\Tridion\Content Porter\temp`

Also, if there are any files - please delete it. I once saw a problem when there were too many files and windows couldn't provide unique filename anymore.

Also, please explore the Tridion event log and Content Porter logs. It would also help if you could post a full exception, including stack trace

Comment: The folder mentioned above is clean.

Comment: Was it working before, or have you just installed it?

Comment: We have working content porter in other environments. This is only failing. We imported content from one environment and tried to import to this environment but importing is failing

Comment: Can you cehck all the logs and post exception, including stacktrace?

Answer (score 3):

In my environment I have this set up for [Tridion]\Content Porter\ImportExportService\Web.config:

Right after `</WebServices>`

```
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200" maxRequestLength="1024000" 
               useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8"
               minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209752100" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```